# Where can I get Zest 2.0 eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, zest

I was trying to get Zest 2.0 for Eclipse marketplace but found nothing.

Then I tried to download it manually through GEF4, however it seems that there are only 1.x versions of Zest.

[image: screenshot]

How can I install Zest 2.0 properly?

Answer (score 1):

The version history of Zest is not entirely clear, but I try to tell what happened there:

- The original versions (Zest 1.x) were developed by Ian Bull, that was included in the GEF project, but was developed mostly separately.
- GEF 2.0 started as a Google Summer of Code project in 2009 (IIRC), and a lot of new features and bugfixes were implemented over the 1.x branch, but they were never ported back to the release train.
- Then GEF4 started as a new approach where the entire inner behaviour of GEF was changed, and in 2014 the Zest 2.0 components were migrated to use the new GEF4 codebase, using a 0.1.0 version number.
- In June 2016 this was released as GEF4 Zest 1.0.

In other words, components called Zest 2.0 are not available in any standalone release. If you want to rely on them, you can do one of the following:

- Use Zest 1.x components available from the GEF legacy release update site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/legacy/releases/ If you have an existing Zest-based tool, these versions should be easy to migrate to.
- Migrate to GEF4 Zest available from current release site http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/ If you plan to start a new project, most likely this is the most promising candidate; similarly, this is the version that is planned to be maintained long-term, so this migration might become necessary sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Click on help menu / install new software, click on add button to add new update site. The update site can be found [here](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.gef/downloads). In your case that *might* be this: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/gef4/updates/releases. You should see this:

[image: update site Zest]

Install it. Or you may be able to install it using local update site (not tried) found here: https://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/index.php.

Comment: installed it with local update site,it worked perfectly.Thanks!